# How do I read a large input byte-wise into an array?

Tags: c++, string, user-input

I'm looking for a way to store a large input, character by character in an array.
For example think user types `324354545434erdfdrr.........6677`. For the first part I need to have its length, (think I only wants to count its alphabets not numbers) then I want to create an array based on its length (number of its alphabets), (a[length]), then I need to store the input, character by character in the array.
What situation you will decide me?

I'm thinking about using

```
getch();
```

function but don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use string in c++?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string str;  
    std::cin >> str;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because string has limits to only 256 characters, but using array I can store a huge number of characters.

Comment: I just tried. string does not have this kind of limitation on my machine. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I just read that strings can only contains 256 chars, I test it never!